# Processing data columns with Perl

Tags: perl

i want to split the columns and get the data using the regex. looking for a simpler solution using backreferences.

`previous balance     payments    adjustments      charges   payment without fine     payment with fine`

`20,251.97                   -          0.00              -           0.00              +         53,391.67            =         73,643.64                74,393.64`

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $regex = qr/^(\d|-)?(\d|,)*\.?\d*$/;
my $data = "20,251.97                   -          0.00              -           0.00              +         53,391.67            =         73,643.64                74,393.64"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you just use the [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function?

```
my @fields = split(/ +/, $data);
```

Comment: And if you want, for some reason, exclude operators `-`, `+` and `=` you could use the pattern `/[ +\-=]+/`.

Answer (score 0):

All your numbers seem to have a common format.  You can write just one regex that works to capture any of your numbers.  Then compose a longer regex that matches your records.

The benefit of this over the split method is that you can ask for a warning if your data doesn't match the format you expect.

```
my $num = qr{
    \s*          # skip whitespace
    (            # begin capture
        [\d,.]+  # comma, period, digits
    )            # end capture
    \s*          # skip whitespace
}x;

my (
    $prev_bal, $pmts_received, $adjustments, $charges, 
    $pmt_without_fine, $pmt_with_fine
) = $data =~ /$num \- $num \- $num \+ $num = $num $num/x
    or warn "Unexpected format: $data\n";
```